# remove duplicate lines from a file

Tags: java, python, c++, linux, multithreading

I have the following data:

```
 number1
 I am writing line1 .
 number2
 First line .
 number3
 I am writing line2.
 number4
 Second line .
 number5
 I am writing line3 .
 number6
 Third line.
 number7
 I am writing line2 .
 number8
 Fourth line .
 number9
 I am writing line5 .
 number10
 Fifth line .
```

Now I want to remove the duplicate lines from this text file -- along with this I want to remove 1 preceding and 2 succeeding lines of the duplicate line. Such that after removal my data looks like:

```
 number1
 I am writing line1 .
 number2
 First line .
 number3
 I am writing line2.
 number4
 Second line .
 number5
 I am writing line3 .
 number6
 Third line.
 number9
 I am writing line5 .
 number10
 Fifth line .
```

The size of my file is 60 GB and I am using a server with 64 GB RAM. I am using the following code for removing the duplicates:

```
fOutput = open('myfile','w')

table_size = 2**16
seen = [False]*table_size
infile = open('test.ttl', 'r')
while True:
    inFileLine1=infile.readline()
    if not inFileLine1:
        break #EOF
    inFileLine2=infile.readline()
    inFileLine3=infile.readline()
    inFileLine4=infile.readline()
    h = hash(inFileLine2) % table_size
    if seen[h]:
        dup = False
        with open('test.ttl','r') as f:
            for line1 in f:
                if inFileLine2 == line1:
                    dup = True
                    break
            if not dup:
                fOutput.write(inFileLine1)
                fOutput.write(inFileLine2)
                fOutput.write(inFileLine3)
                fOutput.write(inFileLine4)
    else:
        seen[h] = True
        fOutput.write(inFileLine1)
        fOutput.write(inFileLine2)
        fOutput.write(inFileLine3)
        fOutput.write(inFileLine4)

fOutput.close()
```

However, it turns out this code is very slow. Is there some way by which I may improve the efficiency of the code using parallelization  i.e. using all 24 cores available to me on my system or using any other technique.

Although the above code is written in python -- but I am fine with efficient solutions in c++ or python or Java or using linux commands

Here test.ttl is my input file with size 60GB

Comment: @tmoreau Actually I am looking for an efficient implementation --- i.e. even if the answer is serial (i.e. does not use parallelization) but is efficient, that is acceptable to me

Comment: Split your data into chunks and process each chunk parallel. I'm not sure, but bash seems to me the worst possible selection. I'd try Java or C++.

Comment: I think it's an algorithms question. It's completely valid to ask it here. The current algorithm is O(N^2) and the questioner clearly wants something better than that. The best algorithm to use probably depends on the number of duplicate lines in relation to the number of non-duplicate lines. Do you know roughly how many duplicates there will be? e.g. 1% of the lines? 50%?

Comment: @JackWhitham There are around 30% duplicate lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your code is reading every line exactly once, and writing every line (that need to be written) also exactly once. Thus there is no way to optimize the algorithm on the file reading - writing part.

I strongly suspect that your code is slow because of the very bad use of Hash table. Your hash table only has size 2^16, while your file may contain about 2^28 lines, assuming an average of 240 bytes per line.

Since you have such a big RAM (enough to contain all the file), I suggest you change the hash table to a size of 2^30. This should help considerably.

Edit:
In this case, you could try to use some very simple Hash function. For example:

```
long long weight[] = {generate some random numbers};
long long Hash(char * s, int length)
{
    long long result = 0;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while (i < length)
    {
        result += s[i] * weight[j ++];
        i += j;
    }
    return result & ((1 << 30) - 1);    // assume that your hash table has size 2^30
}
```

Comment: I tried the speed improved a bit...but it is still slow

Comment: Here are some other things you can do: 1. change to C/C++; 2. use another hash function, which may be faster. Maybe you should first gprof your program to see where is the bottleneck (which I suspect is the hash function).

Comment: Can you suggest some hash function in c/c++...or perhaps an example could be very useful

Comment: See above for an example. If you have some knowledge of how your actual data look like, then you could possibly do better.

Answer (score 2):

If duplicate lines are quite common, then I think the right way to solve the problem is similar to the one you have, but you must use a hash table that can grow on demand and will automatically handle collisions. Try using the Python `set` data type to store lines that were already reached. With `set` you will not need to confirm that duplicate lines really are duplicates; if they're in the `set` already, they are definitely duplicates. This will work, and be quite efficient. However, Python's memory management may not be very efficient, and the `set` data type might grow beyond the available memory, in which case a rethink will be required. Try it.

**Edit**: ok, so `set` grew too large.

For a good solution, you want to avoid repeatedly re-reading the input file. In your original solution, the input file is read again for each possible duplicate, so if there are N lines, the total number of lines read may be up to N^2. Optimization (profiling) and parallelism won't make this better. And, due to the massive file size, you also have a memory constraint which rules out simple tricks like storing all of the lines seen so far in a hash table (like `set`).

Here is my second suggestion. In this suggestion, memory requirements will scale to fit whatever you have available. You will need enough disk space for at least one copy of your input file. The steps form a pipeline - the output from one step is the input of the next.

**Step 1**. I think you are interested in working on groups of 4 lines. You want to keep the whole group of 4, or none of them. Your first step should be to combine each group of 4 lines into a single line. For example:

```
 number1
 I am writing line1 .
 number2
 First line .
 number3
 I am writing line2.
 number4
 Second line .
```

becomes

```
 number1#I am writing line1 .#number2#First line .
 number3#I am writing line2 .#number4#Second line .
```

Note that I used '#' to mark where the line breaks were. This is important. You can use any character here, provided it is not used in any other place in your input file.

**Step 2**. Prepend the line number to each line.

```
 1#number1#I am writing line1 .#number2#First line .
 2#number3#I am writing line2 .#number4#Second line .
```

**Step 3**. Use the Unix `sort` utility (or a Windows port of it). It's already highly optimized. There are even options to do the sort in parallel for extra speed. Sort with the following options:

```
sort '-t#' -k3
```

These `sort` options cause the program to consider only the 3rd field - which is the 2nd line in each group.

**Step 4**. Now step through the output of the previous stage, looking for duplicates, making use of the fact that *they will be next to each other*. Look at the 3rd field. If you find a duplicate line, discard it.

**Step 5**. Reconstruct the order of the original file using another `sort`:

```
sort '-t#' -k1 -n
```

This time, the sort uses the numerical value of the line number (the first field).

**Step 6**. Remove the line number from the start of each line.

**Step 7**. Turn each '#' character back into a newline character. Job done.

Though this seems like a lot of steps, all but steps 3 and 5 only involve a single pass through the input file, so they'll be very fast. N steps for N lines. The sorting steps (3 and 5) are also fast because the `sort` program has been heavily optimized and uses a good sorting algorithm (at most N log N steps for N lines).

Comment: I tried but you are correct set data type grows beyond available memory

Comment: Sets the delimiter between input fields. Normally the delimiter is whitespace but -t allows you to change it to whatever character you want. Put quotes around the character if it has some other meaning to the shell, e.g. # may mark the start of a comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
fOutput = open('myfile','w')
infile = open('test.ttl', 'r')

all_line2 = {}
while True:
    inFileLine1 = infile.readline()
    if not inFileLine1:
        break #EOF
    inFileLine2 = infile.readline()
    _ = infile.readline()
    _ = infile.readline()
    all_line2[inFileLine2] = False
infile.seek(0)    
while True:
    inFileLine1=infile.readline()
    if not inFileLine1:
        break #EOF
    inFileLine2=infile.readline()
    inFileLine3=infile.readline()
    inFileLine4=infile.readline()
    if not all_line2.get(inFileLine2):
        fOutput.write(inFileLine1)
        fOutput.write(inFileLine2)
        fOutput.write(inFileLine3)
        fOutput.write(inFileLine4)
        all_line2[inFileLine2] = True
```

Comment: it gives the same output as input..thus does not help in removing duplicates

Answer (score 1):

Look at [java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) in Java. It is designed to perform well when used by multiple threads that access the map concurrently.

Also, read the file using Java NIO through an Executor fixed thread pool.

To start with you can use this code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Main {
    private static final ConcurrentHashMap map = new ConcurrentHashMap();

    public static class Task implements Runnable {
        private final String line;

        public Task(String line) {
            this.line = line;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // if (!map.containsKey(line))    // not needed
                map.put(line, true);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        String dir_path, file_name;
        Files.lines(Paths.get(dir_path, file_name)).forEach(l -> service.execute(new Task(l)));
        service.shutdown();
        map.keySet().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am a bit weak in Java..but thanks for your input...if possible...can you please explain with the help of an example in Java

Comment: @StegVerner added. I also suggest shift to languages like `C++` or `Java` if you need performance.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use Java for this. And given that the size of the file is 60 GB, Java provides a well suited API for this named `MappedByteBuffer.`

You load the file using a file channel and map the channel using the above API as follows:
`FileChannel fileChannel = new RandomAccessFile(new File(inputFile), "r").getChannel();`

`mappedBuffer = fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fileChannel.size());`

This loads the entire file into memory. For the best efficient performance, map it into chunks (loads 50k bytes)

`mappedBuffer = fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, 50000);`

Now you can iterate over the mappedBuffer and do your processing. Let know for any clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to read the file in a sequence manner. Let's consider some factors affecting performance and possible solutions:

**Language**: vote for C/C++.

**IO**: we can use Memory Mapping that is available on Windows and Linux, on Linux it is the `mmap()` function; basically, this will map the file content to a pointer e.g. `char* data`. Tell me if you are using Windows and need the code.

**Searching for a key**: I suggest to use Binary Search Tree, each time we take a new couple of lines => value, key; we need to traverse the tree to find the key. If found, then skip this and next couple. If not found, then insert this couple into the tree as a new node, at the ending position of the searching; and also write this couple to the output file. Of course, the searching takes O(logN).

Data structure of a node:

```
struct Node {
    char* key;
    unsigned short keyLen;
    char* value;
    unsigned short valueLen;
    Node* leftNode;
    Node* rightNode;
}
```

You can change `unsigned short` to `unsigned char` if relevant. The pointers `key` and `value` actually point to certain positions of the memory block hold by `data`, thus no new memory is allocated to store key and value.

The searching can be further improved by using Bloom Filter. If the filter answers NO (very quickly) then definitively the key is not existed in our tree, no need to traverse the tree anymore. If the answer is YES, then traverse the tree normally. Bloom Filter is implemented in Redis and HBase, please take a look at these open source database systems, if needed.